# Como importar um arquivo csv para o MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, centos, mariadb

Estou iniciando meus estudos em MySQL. Decidi instalar o MariaDB 10.1.14 no CentOS. Desejo criar um database a partir de um arquivo .csv com aproximadamente 166 milhões de linhas. Procurei tutoriais na internet, mas parece que todos eles assumem que o usuário sabe algo a priori a respeito de bancos de dados, o que não é o meu caso. Além disso, estou achando a documentação oficial do MariaDB um pouco complicada, com poucos exemplos.

Isto posto, suponha que eu tenha o arquivo teste.csv e o seu conteúdo é o seguinte:

```
UF,ValorParcela,MêsCompetência
PE,185.00,01/2015
AM,147.00,01/2015
PR,232.00,01/2015
PE,310.00,01/2015
PB,463.00,01/2015
CE,182.00,01/2015
AL,112.00,01/2015
MG,112.00,01/2015
BA,112.00,01/2015
```

Vamos supor que eu queira importar o conteúdo deste teste.csv para um database bolsa. Até o momento, descobri que preciso fazer o seguinte:

```
CREATE DATABASE bolsa;
USE bolsa;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE teste.csv;
INTO TABLE bolsa
FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Só que este código não está correto. As mensagens de erro não são claras para mim. Eu apreciaria muito se alguém pudesse me dar uma luz de como resolver esta parada.

Comment: Você já criou a tabela bolsa? Você nesse código está a criar a base de dados bolsa, mas não vejo nenhuma menção á tabela bolsa (que deveria ter outro nome). Se possível coloque as mensagens de erro que estão a surgir.

Comment: Faz tanto tempo que eu tive este problema que desisti dele. Acabei resolvendo de outra maneira, sem utilizar MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Tente ignorando a primeira linha e passando o caminho completo do arquivo csv:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/teste.csv';
INTO TABLE bolsa
FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Fonte: 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: Então... Eu já tinha achado este link. Eu não consigo utilizar a sugestão dele, mesmo usando LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/marcus/teste.csv', que é o endereço do arquivo no meu computador.

Comment: Tenta realizar o comando pelo terminal ao invés do mariadb.

Comment: O que significa "realizar o comando pelo terminal"? Fazer pelo bash? Não funciona, pois ele não reconhece o comando LOAD.

Comment: significa abrir um console do mysql pelo bash e executar o SQL por lá... da uma olhada aqui como abrir ele: http://www.devfuria.com.br/sql/mysql-pelo-terminal/

Answer (score -1):

A resposta de Vitor Nascimento é correta. Mas em muitos casos o servidor MySQL não autoriza o uso do comando "LOAD DATA INFILE"
Para verificar isso:
Connectar usando um Terminal, e digitar:

```
 mysql -u root -p
 show variable like "%local%";
```

Isso vai mostra a valor do parâmetro local_infile que deve ter a valor 'on'
A outra coisa a verificar e se o usuário tem o direito "FILE" na tabela (direto diferente do INSERT por exemplo)
Para isso:

```
  select user,File_priv from mysql.user;
```

Vai dar uma tabela com direito de cada usuário (y = sim, n = não)

Outra opção se vc não sabe usar o Terminal, e usar PHPMyAdmin ou Adminer (pessoalmente, eu não uso mais PHPMyAdmin porque é pesado)
Da uma olhada no "Privilegio" do usuário, para ver si ele tem o direto 'FILE' e no nivel dos parâmetros do Servidor, verifica a valor da variável local_infile

Answer (score -1):

O erro está no ";" depoi do path do arquivo. Se tirar vai funcionar que é uma beleza

CREATE DATABASE bolsa;
USE bolsa;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "c:/teste.csv"
INTO TABLE bolsa
FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: Olá Odisley, isso é um comentário gerado automaticamente quando a pergunta/resposta é sinalizada. Pode editar a pergunta e melhorar seu formato e explicar a solução para que fique caracterizada como uma boa resposta. Se não souber como, [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/496238/edit) ou no link "Editar" abaixo da pergunta para editá-la

Answer (score -1):

Vamos la, você precisa armazenar estes valores em uma tabela. O seu erro é querer armazenar eles numa Database ou Banco de Dados. O Banco de dados serve para armazenar as tabelas, após ter criado o seu banco de dados com comando:

```
CREATE DATABASE bolsa;
```

Você precisa seguir com o que você ja fez, vamos usar o Banco de Dados bolsa com comando:

```
USE bolsa;
```

Após isso, vamos para o passo que faltou pra você que é criar uma **TABELA**, com comando:
OBS: As colunas tem que ser equivalentes as que tem no CSV.

```
CREATE TABLE estados (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
UF VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
valor_parcela VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
mes_competencia DATE NOT NULL 
);
```

Depois de criar a tabela, ai que você vai inserir os valores, conforme abaixo:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/marcus/teste.csv' 
INTO TABLE users 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(UF, valor_parcela, @mes_competencia)
SET mes_competencia = STR_TO_DATE(@mes_competencia, '%m/%y');
```

Vou explicar cada detalhe acima:

- O comando **LOCAL** é onde o arquivo é esperado de ser encontrado.
  O seu programa vai ler o arquivo, através do seu host e enviar para o servidor, para saber mais indicor você ler o documentação [Documentação de Referência](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).
- Como a virgular é o delimitador, usamos **FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’**.
- Cada linha do CSV é encerrada com um caractere de nova linha **LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’**
- Ja temos a descrição das colunas na tabela criada, por isso ignoramos a primeira linha do arquivo CSV que são os nomes da tabela **IGNORE 1 ROWS**.
- O formato padrão de datas para um tabela de banco de dados, é YYYY-MM-DD. Como você esta usando formato de data diferente no seu CSV, sendo mês/ano, diferente do esperado, por isso precisamos alterar o formato usando a função **STR_TO_DATE()**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Fiz um teste em um simulador e funcionou.

**OBS:** O teste foi feito em um Editor e Compilador Online, por isso não da pra considerar liralmente o erro apresentado, até porque não tenho este arquivo também.

[image: Teste feito em um Editor e Compilador Online, por isso não da pra considerar liralmente o erro apresentado, até porque não tenho este arquivo também.]

Fonte: [How to import a CSV file into a MySQL database?](https://medium.com/@AviGoom/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-mysql-database-ef8860878a68#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEzZThkNDVhNDNjYjIyNDIxNTRjN2Y0ZGFmYWMyOTMzZmVhMjAzNzQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJuYmYiOjE2MTcyNzkwNzUsImF1ZCI6IjIxNjI5NjAzNTgzNC1rMWs2cWUwNjBzMnRwMmEyamFtNGxqZGNtczAwc3R0Zy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwOTAwNTk1NjI0MjMxNDk3OTA2NyIsImVtYWlsIjoiY2FpcXVlc2FuZHJhZGU5NEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXpwIjoiMjE2Mjk2MDM1ODM0LWsxazZxZTA2MHMydHAyYTJqYW00bGpkY21zMDBzdHRnLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwibmFtZSI6IkNhaXF1ZSBBbmRyYWRlIiwicGljdHVyZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbGgzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbS9hLS9BT2gxNEdndFRLVEdXdVRnNExGaE80WGtlUWFVdGJ5MVZmVVpWUmxzR29yN2Uxdz1zOTYtYyIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJDYWlxdWUiLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6IkFuZHJhZGUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTcyNzkzNzUsImV4cCI6MTYxNzI4Mjk3NSwianRpIjoiN2EyNDQ2YmJkYzQ4NjY4YmRkNmUxMGQwMGUzZDQwMzIzNDYxNWU1NiJ9.K7Atflz38Z4QLNCgHXItvbDlFQG0xX-BMTYLyooJUY8bpkaGyGRnTqJSiBKW99XCU82L_qBmiX4qMrEwIPJQngucGl80M4toPovjy70ZysOsKiAGSCjMQNam43o1nIcCFQpNLtyZqhTv09WQDn98Ol-gnHxYQFFFuYkQ8Nx-askOkLs_6IavrFBfivnz2_TunSoN-trxXxFN7eGsp5OsN_pA3fyZR9JFoh19ReUvxqgOCSeQ0AjN4OISflsNF6YkuSLn9Vq_6QLaSFlE7AiTocCOLTqhncxqiWC8zHqKsANnLEwPGA1Srv1s9jAKcEvk7FZBs4OI3vM-n0MdgHCLyQ)